# ASP.NET Web API: Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, stream, mono, server-sent-events

I'm trying to do low latency data pushing from the server to the client with HTTP.

I'm using ASP.NET Web API and I have this in my controller:

```
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i.ToString()));
            response.Flush();

            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
```

This should send the numbers 0 to 9 to the client every 200 milliseconds but it adds an error message to the stream saying that "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent." I's not even an exception I can catch... i'ts just writing error page HTML to the response stream....

In this example I'm not even using any custom headers... It doesn't make any sense. I got it to work somehow while trying different things, but when I deployed it to staging I got the same behavior the difference is that the staging server runs it on Ubuntu with Mono and Apache instead of IIS on Windows with regular .NET.

I'm looking for an explanation of why it does this more than a fix...